# Unable to get microfrontend's assets with Single-SPA and Vite

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vite, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a Single-SPA application with a root-config (running on port 9000) and a Vite-Vue app (running on port 9001). However, when I run the app, the png file from the Vite-Vue app is not fetched in localhost:9000 and it throws 404.

[image][image]

I did some research but didn't find much helpful info. I thought that I might need to modify the file vite.config, so I used this Vite [feature](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) to modify the assets URL when trying to fetch the image:

```
<template>
  <img id="logo" alt="Vue logo" v-bind:src="getImageUrl('logo')" /> ----> function added to src
  <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3.0 + Vite" />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
const imgUrl = new URL('./assets/logo.png', import.meta.url).href


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
    getImageUrl(name) { ----> created function to modify the url 
      const a = new URL(`./assets/logo.png`, import.meta.url).href
      console.log(a)
      return new URL(`./assets/${name}.png`, import.meta.url).href
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I created the function getImageUrl to change './assets/logo.png' to '/localhost:9000/src/assets/logo.png' and added it to the img src, and I have the following vite.config file:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
  rollupOptions: {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    format: 'system',
    preserveEntrySignatures: true,
    output: {
      assetFileNames: (asset) => {
        if (asset === 'logo') {
          return "/src/assets/logo.png";
        }
      }
    },
  },
  base: 'http://localhost:8001',
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      transformAssetUrls: {
        base: '/src'
      }
    }
  })],
}
```

This didn't work and I'm not sure if I'm in the correct way to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. If you know a solution only in React it's also ok.

Comment: I think the problem is that your image does not become part of the exported project. The image should not be fetched from the `src` folder. Your bundler should copy it to the assets folder. You can achieve that by using `import myimage from "./images/bla.png"` in your source code.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the issues indeed. And I also had to add server: {origin: "http://localhost:8001"} to vite.config (outside rollupOptions). That output in the rollup options is not needed, neither is the method getImageUrl(name)